# Dataframe manipulation

Tags: python, pandas

Goal:  To add a column to a dataframe consisting of labels as follows:

```
(-10,5]=-2

(-5,0]= -1

[0,5)  = 0

[5,10)=  1

[10,15)= 2
```

....etc

If the `df.ptdelta` is between `(-10,5]` it receives -2 added to a column of `df`.

Attempt 1:

```
df=pd.read_csv("___.csv",names="a b c d e f".split())
df.set_index(["a", "b"], inplace=True)
d=df["d"]<5 
u=df["d"]>=0

p=df["d"][d & u]
```

This appears to find no instances: `Series([], dtype=object)`

But indeed there are doubles in `df["d"]` within this range.

Attempt 2:

```
zero=[x for x in df["d"] if (0<=df["d"]) & (df["d"]<5)]
```

Which results in:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Why do either of these fail? Many thanks.

```
df.head() gives: 

        price   ptdelta     II  pl
date    time                
date    time    price   ptdelta II  pl
1/5/2009    930     842     0   -   0
            1620    845.2   3.2     -   6.6
1/6/2009    930     851.8   6.6     -      -3.6
            1620    848.2   -3.6    -   -13
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binning the data and labeling it by bin. Happily, `numpy.digitize` can do that for you.

```
bins = [-10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15]
labels = np.digitize(data, bins) - 3
```

Example:

```
In[1]: df = DataFrame({'d': np.random.randint(-20, 20, 100)})

In[2]: bins = [-10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15]

In[3]: df['labels'] = np.digitize(df['d'], bins) - 3

In[4]: df.head()
Out[4]:
   d  labels
0 -8      -2
1  4       0
2 -7      -2
3 -3      -1
4  5       1
```

These bins are closed on the left, like [-10, 5). I think the bins you specified are not self-consistent. (Should I label 0 as -1 or 0?) Anyway, if the edge cases are crucial, see the documentation for more options.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html

Any data points less than -10 or greater than 15 will be labeled -3 and 3, respectively. You can discard them if need be.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. It seems that df['d'] is not agreeable(for my existing df["d"]) consisting of doubles: "TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type" I tried casting it to a list first which also didn't work. Also why do you subtract 3?

Comment: ``np.digitize`` labels the bins starting with 1. You label the bins starting with -2.

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of that error. Can you post the output of ``df.head()``?

Comment: Sure, I edited above to share df.head(). I actually label bins between [-60,60] (I was just writing that for the sake of simplicity).

Comment: It looks like your input file starts with a header of labels, and these maybe mucking up your data. Try passing ``skiprows=3`` to ``read_csv``.